# Tibco Spotfire, how to insert yesterday column based on current date

Tags: datetime, spotfire

Tibco Spotfire, how to insert yesterday column based on current date.

how to insert calculated column for an yesterday based on current date time.

i.e:

```
if current date: 08/09/2016 (dd/mm/yyyy)
 ---------------------
 | price | yesterday |
 ---------------------
 |  100  | 07/09/2016|
 |  150  | 07/09/2016|
 ---------------------
```

Comment: there's an function in custom expression: datetimenow() which gives current datetime but doesn't support subtraction, so can't find yesterday date from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DATEADD('dd',-1,DATE(DATETIMENOW()))`. If you remove the `DATE()` part it will include the time as well.